# open one more tab when come on my webpage

Tags: javascript

I will try to explain what I look for, when someone open my webpage automatically open one more tab with other url.
For example, someone find my webpage in google, when they click it and his/her browser opens a second tab with other url along with the first web page that is clicked.

Comment: for example u have popular webpage, and u want to promote new one site, when user open u page in same time opened extra one page with ur promouting url

Comment: look for how to use `window.open`

Comment: Offtopic, but when I visit site that does something like this it pretty much guarantees I won't visit the site again :)

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt - I don't think you're Robinson Crusoe in that regard

Comment: I add that script 
    window.open(' www.mydomain.com', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0'); to my page page, but its give popup when open. How to make without pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

Grab the onfocus event on your existing webpage and call window.open for the new website url with target _blank.